# Embed hidden text in Android `SmsMessage`

Tags: android, encryption, sms

As the title of my questions suggests, I am looking for a way to embed hidden text inside of a `SMS` message. I am unsure if this is possible and have spent a fair amount of time scouring the documentation from Android at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html.

This following link provides information about the structure of an SMS message http://www.smartposition.nl/resources/sms_pdu.html as it may be of use to the reader.

I am seeking the confirmation or rejection that this is possible, and if it is, will the method provided be platform/application independent?

Thanks all for you help and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really possible. You have no control over how any given SMS app chooses to display received messages. It may be possible to encode something within the text using non-printing characters, but it would have to be your app that receives and decodes the message. The same goes for any kind of encoding or encryption you might implement. No standard SMS client is going to know to specially handle your messages.

Comment: Are you suggesting to convert the `SMS` from `ascii` (the default) to a binary string to add the non-printing characters? Or is it somehow possible to achieve this through the `ascii` default.

Comment: AFAIK, there are only about two non-printing characters in the default alphabet, and I believe those are reserved control characters, which means they might not even make it through transmission. You'd probably have to use a 16-bit alphabet, especially to encode anything meaningful in the limited message size available. There again, though, your app would have to be the one to read and decode it.

Comment: Also, if you do intend for your app to be the recipient, another possibility is data SMS. Those are discarded by the Provider, so they won't show in any other SMS client, including the native app.